# how do i get fields value of webform before entering into database?

Tags: webforms

I want value of a hidden field of webform in custom module so that i could match it with other value from database to validate it

Answer (score 1):

You can use `hook_form_alter` to achieve this in your custom module.

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_form_alter().
 */

function your_custom_module_name_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  // Add validation for a particular Webform node:
  if ($form_id == 'webform_id') {
    // Simply add the additional validate handler.
    $form['#validate'][] = 'mycustom_extra_validate';

    //$first = array_shift($form['#submit']);
    //array_unshift($form['#submit'], $first, 'mycustom_extra_submit');
  }
}

/**
 * Validation handler for Webform .
 */
function mycustom_extra_validate(&$form, &$form_state) {
  //condition to check validation
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am just giving the example how you can access hidden field in custom module,in my case i have added value to hidden field by doing custom code,you can take reference of below code:

```
function your_module_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){

 if ($form_id == 'webform_client_form_28') {

  $uid = arg(1);
   if ( arg(0) == 'user' && is_numeric($uid) ) {
       $account = user_load($uid);
       $form['submitted']['user_email']['#value'] = $account->mail;
       $form['submitted']['uid']['#value']=$uid;
   }
 }
}
```